# Is it possible to implement a Flickr-like justified gallery in pure CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been using [miromannino.github.io](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) as gallery layout for a few pages and recently I've been trying to figure out if it's possible to do this in raw CSS, potentially with flexbox.

The problem is in the varying horizontal and vertical pictures and that they should always fill 100% of the container width. The closest I got was:

```
.jgal {
  max-width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.jgalimg {
  display: block;
  align-self: flex-start;
  max-height: 40vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

on a layout like:

```
<div class="jgal">
    <a class="jgallink" href="url-to-img.jpg">
        <img class="jgalimg hor" src="url-to-thumb.jpg" width="640" height="480" />
    </a>
    <a class="jgallink" href="url-to-img-2.jpg">
        <img class="jgalimg ver" src="url-to-thumb-2.jpg" width="480" height="640" />
    </a>
    [ ... ]
</div>
```

I have the sizes and the orientation as class. I've tried using

```
align-content: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
```

but then aligning the image size to the a tag becomes tricky.

So, any ideas? :)

Answer (score 8):

Although the question is more than a year old, I was trying to work out the same thing recently and I came up with the following fully responsive CSS-only Flickr-like justified gallery solution:

```css
.jg {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.jg > a, .jg::after {
  --ratio: calc(var(--w) / var(--h));
  --row-height: 9rem;
  flex-basis: calc(var(--ratio) * var(--row-height));
}

.jg > a {
  margin: 0.25rem;
  flex-grow: calc(var(--ratio) * 100);
}

.jg::after {
  --w: 2;
  --h: 1;
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1000000;
}

.jg > a > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="jg">

  <a href="#" style="--w: 200; --h: 300">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 300; --h: 200">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 500; --h: 400">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x400">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 300; --h: 300">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 300; --h: 400">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 400; --h: 300">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 200; --h: 300">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 400; --h: 300">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--w: 300; --h: 500">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x500">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Pretty clever! I tweaked it a bit to allow full last-row expanding, added a max-height for images and min-width for columns: https://codepen.io/nicooprat/pen/KGzRaJ

Comment: This solution requires priming the image dimensions in an inline style. Doe that not defeat the whole purpose of not using js as you would need some form of js to get the dimensions?

Comment: @BenjaminGoodacre Image size on its own is very generic and layout-agnostic information about an image. This can be set on a server along with image url info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is with the `max-width: 90vw` there, but you can accomplish this with a fixed size of thumbnails. The CSS below will scale the image to fill the container, cropping it centered vertically and horizontally.

```
.jgal {
  /* set font-size to 0 to avoid the whitespace between HTML elements causing spaces between the photos */
  font-size: 0;
}
a.jgallink {
  /* set desired image size */
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;

  /* set space between photos */
  margin-right: 1px;

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

img.jgalimg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

img.jgalimg.ver {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[open in codepen](http://codepen.io/aaronpk/pen/vgOGgq)

This was adapted from [this blog post](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/) which got the technique from the Wordpress media library.

Comment: The "set desired image size" is the problem; how do you deal with varying aspect ratios, varying horizontal/vertical images? Please see the linked JS solution; that is the goal in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation via `flexbox`.

```
.jgal{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.jgal a{
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
}

.jgal img{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1wrn8k4v/2/

Comment: This is a single line implementation. For that, it's fine, but what if there are significantly more images? Please see the linked JS gallery; that is what I would like to replace.

Comment: It's possible to break them into multiple rows but then you have to set widths and it doesn't look quite as organic anymore. This was a fun experiment :)  https://jsfiddle.net/1wrn8k4v/3/

Comment: Is there a way to do this without object-fit: cover?