# Can CSS scale a set of images to fit together (like Google Photos)?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Google Photos takes images of various sizes and scales them so that the images in each row have the same height and each row completely fills the width of the window.

For instance:

[image: 11 photos nicely packed together in three rows]

If the window is narrower, it rearranges them accordingly:

[image: Same 11 photos in four rows.]

I could do this with JavaScript, but is there CSS that can achieve the same thing?

Comment: CSS can scale images with different classes to different sizes, but i don't think you can do it based on any formula. Minimally, you need javascript to set the css class.

Comment: CSS is not a programming language and can't do stuff like that by itself. With media query's, Flexbox (or CSS Grid) and known ratio's ,one could reorder images in a similar way, but it would take a lot of work.

Comment: What @LGSon said is true. A pure CSS solution depends heavily on known dimensions of the container and the contained images. The go to move for a solution like this is a JS masonry layout solution. Here are 2 good ones: https://masonry.desandro.com/v3/, https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments to this question have confirmed what I suspected, that **it can't be achieved by CSS alone**.

@BugsArePeopleToo has given a good reference for a JavaScript library that does what I want, and more: https://masonry.desandro.com/v3/ and https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

I like to keep it simple and prefer to roll my own, but I didn't want to write the JS myself if some CSS feature that I didn't know about would do it.  It doesn't, so I did end up rolling my own.

In case anyone wants to do the same, here's my first draft.  It works well, but I haven't yet decided how best to handle when the last row doesn't get filled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <title>Tile Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        *   { box-sizing: border-box; }
        div { border-width: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; }
        img { border-width: 0; padding: 0; margin: auto; height: 99%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tile Test</h1>
    <div id="tileMe">
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0240.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0250.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0260.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0270.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0280.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0290.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0300.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0310.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0320.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0330.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=".Images/B0340.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
<script> "use strict"
    window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
        resize("tileMe", 14)
    }
    var pixelsPerEm = function(element) {
        var width
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        div.style.width = "1000em"
        element.appendChild(div)
        width = div.offsetWidth
        element.removeChild(div)
        return width / 1000
    }
    var findAspectRatio = function(images, count) {
        var i
        var aspect = 0
        for (i=0; i<count; ++i)
            aspect += images[i].naturalWidth / images[i].naturalHeight
        return aspect
    }
    var makeDiv = function(container, aspect, images, count) {
        var i
        var div = document.createElement("div")
        div.style.height = (container.clientWidth / aspect) + "px"
        div.style.display = "flex"
        for (i=0; i<count; ++i)
            div.appendChild(images.shift())
        container.appendChild(div)
    }
    var resize = function(id, maxEms) {
        var aspect, count, i
        var container = document.getElementById(id)
        var maxHeight = pixelsPerEm(container) * maxEms
        var images = Array.from(container.getElementsByTagName("img"))
        while (container.lastChild) container.removeChild(container.lastChild)
        while (images.length) {
            for (i=1; i<=images.length; ++i) {
                count = i
                aspect = findAspectRatio(images, i)
                if (container.clientWidth / aspect < maxHeight)
                    break
                aspect = container.clientWidth / maxHeight
            }
            makeDiv(container, aspect, images, count)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to this question, but hopefully this will help other visitors.

The specific layout in the screenshot is called a Justified Grid Gallery, or a Justified Gallery. The links are for a different type of layout, called Masonry, which stacks items vertically (with items being scaled to the *same width in a column*), while a justified grid arranges them horizontally (with items being scaled to the *same height in a row*). One small difference is that using a Justified Grid you can get the items in the last row to fill out the entire row, but in a masonry layout, unless you allow for variations in the column widths, your columns end up being of different heights.

The easiest way to lay it out is as Ray has suggested, using JS. There are some specific libraries that help do this, the most famous being https://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/.

That being said, if you know of the dimensions of the images, Flexbox can get you to your layout using pure CSS. There is an answer here for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107319. This makes smart use of `calc` and `var`. So, if you are serving your page using PHP or some server-based framework, **and** you have access to the sizes, you could pre-populate the sizes in the markup, and then let the CSS take over for you. Pre-populating the image dimensions helps address CLS (cumulative layout shift) issues as well.

Some things to watch out for: `var` is not supported in IE 11 and lower. So if you require to support IE, you will need the JavaScript hook for it.

As a matter of personal preference, I think the JS approach is a lot more reliable if you don't trust the sizes returned by the server - an incorrect size hammers the aspect ratio of some photos horribly. But if you have full control of the size information, the CSS approach works out quite cleanly.